# Command Line - Enable Remote Login and Remote Management

Tags: macos, command-line, sharing, remote-control

For my job, before I deploy a new Mac laptop, I need to enable these two settings:

1. System Preferences - Sharing - Remote Login.  Once enabled I also need to add the admin account that previously I have created by selecting the little + symbol under Only these users:
2. System Preferences - Sharing - Remote Management - (the little pop up windows comes out) and I select all the features

How do I achieve the above two process via command line?

Comment: Which deployment solution do you use? DeployStudio, Casper or scripts?

Comment: neither.  i just ssh into the machine to do stuff.  But I need to enable the two steps above before I do that for different reasons.

Answer (score 24):

Modifying remote login and remote management settings is done with two different commands - both executed as root:

- systemsetup
- kickstart

To enable remote login for members of the admin group enter:

```
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

To restrict access use `dseditgroup`. First check if it exists and add it if necessary:

```
dseditgroup com.apple.access_ssh
dseditgroup -o create -q com.apple.access_ssh
```

and add a user group:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a admin -t group com.apple.access_ssh
```

To enable remote management for admin users enter:

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -users admin -privs -all -restart -agent -menu
```

To check other options enter:

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart --help
```

Comment: since 10.14  you cannot enable via ssh. If Yo connect via ssh, You got:   


Warning: macos 10.14 and later only allows control if Screen Sharing is enabled through System Preferences.

Answer (score 16):

Enabling SSH:

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Disabling SSH:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

(the alternative, `systemsetup` is deprecated)

```
This command still works, but it is deprecated. Please use launchctl(8) instead.
```

Comment: Very helpful.  I had a script, running as root, that used the systemsetup command.  However, in Catalina, it was not working, as it needed Full Disk Access (SystemPolicyAllFiles)  but did not have a way to prompt the user for it.  Using the launchctl command worked perfectly.

Comment: exactly @TimDearborn - also that "Full Disk Access" needed for on off that function, I consider as flaw

Comment: `systemsetup` is not deprecated anymore as far as I can tell (I cannot find `dep` in the man page anywhere) and don't receive any message like that when running it. Also, don't see a prompt for Full Disk Access being needed (this is on Big Sur and Monterey at least). Also, `launchctl load` is considered legacy as of 'Yosemite'. Instead, should be using `sudo launchctl bootstrap system ...`.