# How to change password using bash script?

Tags: macos, applescript, bash, script

I know the admin password. What script I need to use to change password and enable Remote Login and Remote Management

Comment: I already answered this for you in the first question you asked about this:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315478/change-local-admin-passwords-across-the-network

Answer (score 3):

## Change Password

You can change a user's password from the command line using the `dscl` tool:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/cedge
```

See krypted's [Mac OS X: Changing Passwords from the Command Line](http://krypted.com/mac-security/mac-os-x-changing-passwords-from-the-command-line).

## Remote Login and Management

See the related question [Command Line - Enable Remote Login and Remote Management](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278744/command-line-enable-remote-login-and-remote-management#278763):

> To enable remote login for members of the admin group enter:
>
> ```
> sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
> ```
>
> …
>
> To enable remote management for admin users enter:
>
> ```
> sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -access -on -users admin -privs -all -restart -agent -menu
> ```